# How to substitute the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() by Task.Factory.StartNew()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, lambda, task-parallel-library

Having the working code below in C# 3.0, how can I convert it to C# 4.0 having substituted the line

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LongGetOrAdd(dict, 1));
```

by

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(//?
```

?

The complete code of working C# 3.0 console application:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LongGetOrAdd(dict, 1));

//???????
//Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(LongGetOrAdd(dict, 1));

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue:");
    foreach (var a in dict)
    Console.WriteLine("dict.Key = {0}  dict.Value = {1}  ", a.Key, a.Value);


    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  private static WaitCallback LongGetOrAdd(ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dict, int index)
  {
    return o => dict.GetOrAdd
    (index, 
     i =>
       {
         Console.WriteLine("From method LongGetOrAdd()!");
         Thread.SpinWait(1000);
         return i.ToString();
       }
    );
  }
}
```

producing output:

```
Press enter to continue:
From method LongGetOrAdd()!

dict.Key = 1  dict.Value = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do.

```
    var c = LongGetOrAdd(dict, 1);

    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Invoke(null));

    Task.WaitAll(task);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Look at the code.  `LongGetOrAdd` *creates a delegate* it doesn't do the work.

Comment: actually it shouldnt since its delegate. I edited .. so edited version should work but..

Comment: @Servy, the method outputs the value `"======!"` to Console and fills the dictionary with `key==1` and `value=="======!"`. The intention was not to change functionality but just to change thread's launching and method call by `Task.Factory.StartNew()` equivalently

Comment: @Fulproof If you want to comment on my answer you should really **comment on my answer** rather than commenting on someone else's answer or editing a reply into the question.  Next, my code doesn't change any functionality at all, it maintains the same functionality as your code, unlike this answer which actually changes the functionality by adding `Task.WaitAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the type of delegate that `LongGetOrAdd` returns and call the other method.

You'll also need to remove the parameter from the lambda, since you're not actually passing in any information.

All of this is clearly indicated by the compiler/intellisense when simply looking at the signature of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

```
private static Action LongGetOrAdd(ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dict, int index)
{
    return () => dict.GetOrAdd
    (index,
     i =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine("======!");
         Thread.SpinWait(1000);
         return i.ToString();
     }
    );
}
private static void Main()
{
    var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(LongGetOrAdd(dict, 1));

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit . . .");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: it is indicated by Intellisense after it was correctly written once otherwise Intellisense gives a signature + 15 its overloads

Comment: @Fulproof If you were to simply change nothing other than the method name you would see a syntax error indicating the improper delegate type; you would simply need to change the delegate to the matching one.  As for the overloads, simply start with the ones with the least parameters and move up as needed.  In this case, you want one of the two one-parameter overloads.  If you're particularly confused or curious, there's always Google with literally *millions* of examples.

Comment: Servy, thanks but the intention was not changing method or any functionality in any way. The question did not ask this

Comment: @Fulproof This answer does *not* change any functionality in any way; it results in identical functionality but through using the TPL classes rather than the `System.Threading` classes, which is *exactly* what you asked for.

Comment: @Fulproof What did it change exactly?

Comment: @Fulproof Changing the type of the delegate won't cause any functional change at all.  You must have made some other change than what I described that resulted in your error.

Comment: Servy, could you possibly post the complete code because I cannot manage to compile your changes and have no clue how to introduce into code from my question?

Comment: @Fulproof Edited in, although nothing that I didn't show needed to be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cannot understand why my projects are unstable (giving erratic non-reproducible results)

Comment: @Fulproof It's because you're using multiple threads without properly synchronizing them.  The fact that it's not reproducible is entirely expected.

Comment: It's because I am having clinging (making short circuit) Ctrl key on keyboard, so instead of launching projects in debugging mode by F5 (with rebuilding) I am launching in Release mode (as Ctrl+F5) without re-building project